# Misalignment of load segments

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

In linux kernel version 4.14.41, Error occurs whenever the LOAD segment that is aligned is not a multiple of 2MB. But why not the same check performed in linux kernel version 3.16.0 ? Also, Why isn't this check being performed for any veriosn's 32-bit configured kernel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The check for alignment of LOAD Segments at a multiple of 2MB for 64-bit is released in linux-4.9.91 release. The following is the code snippet of `arch/x86/Makefile` :

```
 #The 64-bit kernel must be aligned to 2MB.  Pass -z max-page-size=0x200000 to
 #the linker to force 2MB page size regardless of the default page size used
 #by the linker.
 ifdef CONFIG_X86_64
 LDFLAGS += $(call ld-option, -z max-page-size=0x200000) 
 endif
```

This type of passing is not present in previous versions but yet the 64-bit LOAD Sections align at a multiple of 2MB. If such alignment is not followed, then the versions 4.9.91 and above would produce the error `Alignment of LOAD Segments is not a multiple of 2MB` whereas the other versions produce the error `Kernel is not a valid ELF file`